# Clean halt in Linux Kernel

Tags: linux-kernel

I need to execute a few machine instructions just before kernel "halts".

Reason is I need to inform a board controller it can actually remove power.

**Question** is: what is the best-practice to achieve this?

In an old (3.18) kernel for the same board I hacked `.../arch/mips/ralink/reset.c` to add some register settings in static void `ralink_halt(void)` but that function seems gone together with static `int __init mips_reboot_setup(void)`, so i guess structure changed a lot since then.

What is the correct hook to use in modern kernels?

Comment: Normally the kernel driver for the board would implement a shutdown call.